# How to solve this issue "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri' "

Tags: flutter, dart

> Error at line "URL + baptismalForm.toParams()"

> Error shows: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type

```dart
class FormController {
  final void Function(String) callback;
  static const String URL =
      'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxrRrkipd6wx6y2X3duzn2QYdJFFuvzypUCDchEQVc3X3N62pyt7RUMYHr8fckeiw0/exec';

  static const STATUS_SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";

  FormController(this.callback);

  void submitForm(BaptismalForm baptismalForm) async {
    try {
      await http.get(URL + baptismalForm.toParams()).then((response) {
        callback(convert.jsonDecode(response.body)['status']);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert String to Uri, like

```dart
_url = Uri.parse( stringUrl );
```

Try like

```dart
final _url = Uri.parse(URL + baptismalForm.toParams());
await http.get(_url).then((response) {
```